# google data studio - i get incorrect value when i do a multiplication on CPC

Tags: looker-studio, google-ads-api

My problem is the value of **CPC** displayed after a multiplication  "not correct"

Example :  my CPC = 0.02 $

and i want to multiply the CPC by 10.5 
i tried to do  CPC * 10.5 but the result is 0.17 instead of 0.21

For information :  i get data from google ads

thank you a lot in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Decimal Precision** in [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479) is set to 2 places by default, thus one possibility is that the value of `0.02` in the `CPC moy` field is rounded from `0.0165`.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/de3de4b4-b736-4aee-8d3c-cdaa6c6eb876) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]